Rest assured basic authentication scheme does not work anymore
I have been working on upgrading one of our microservices to Spring Boot 2.7.8 -> 3.1.5 during this activity I encountered a problem when it was not possible to set AuthenticationScheme in RestAssured:
    def setup() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost"
        RestAssured.port = this.port
        RestAssured.authentication = new BasicAuthScheme(userName: "user", password:"password")
    }

We use spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier:4.0.4 and Spock 2.4-M1-groovy-4.0
It had been working in the Spring Boot 2.7.8 and has stopped working. I can see in the logs that the authorization header is not sent. The only solution is to provide an authorization header in every contract. Did anyone meet with this issue?

I have already created the issue on github https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1791
